# Do matrix-orthogonal vectors have to be eigenvectors of the matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, quadratic-forms

Say there is a square symmetric matrix $\mathbf{M}$ and vector $\mathbf{v}$. Then the vector $\mathbf{\tilde{v}}$ satisfying

$$\mathbf{\tilde{v}' Mv}=0$$

is said to be $\mathbf{M}$-orthogonal to $\mathbf{v}$ (for eg. page 48 of "Portfolio Theory" by Giorgio P. Szego, 1980).

Noting that the eigenvectors of $\mathbf{M}$ also satisfy this relation, i.e.:

$$\mathbf{e}_i' \mathbf{Me}_{j\neq i}=0$$

May I conclude that $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{\tilde{v}}$ are eigenvectors of $\mathbf{M}$?

Put another way, do there exist vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{\tilde{v}}$ satisfying the first displayed equation which are not eigenvectors of $\mathbf{M}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $M$ be a rank 1 projection matrix, say $M=vv^t$ for some unit length $v\in\mathbb{R}^n,n>1$. So $M$ has one eigenvector, $v$. Let $\tilde{v}$ be a vector orthogonal to $v$ and then $\tilde{v}'Mv=\tilde{v}'v=0,$ although $\tilde{v}$ isn't an eigenvector.

Comment: What about symmetric matrices?

Comment: $(vv^t)^t=(v^t)^tv^t=vv^t$

Comment: Oops.  What I meant to say was: what about symmetric matrices with full rank?

Comment: Let $M$ be square symmetric and full rank $n$ and $v_1,\ldots,v_n$  eigenvectors. So $Mv_1=\lambda v_1,\lambda\in\mathbb{R},$ and you can take a nontrivial linear combination of the other eigenvectors as $\tilde{v}$. The eigenvectors are orthogonal so $\tilde{v}^t(\lambda v)=0$. But clearly not any linear combination is an eigenvector for most $M$.

Comment: So $\tilde{v}$ must be either one of the other eigenvectors, or a linear combination thereof?

Comment: Yeah but this isn't a real restriction since from our assumption that the matrix is full rank and square, every vector in the space is a linear combination of the eigenvectors.